# access ubuntu machines within and outside local network

Tags: linux, ssh

I have two ubuntu machines behind a same tp-link router. client ssh comes already installed with them, and I have installed Open-ssh as ssh daemon for remote access. I have also added a port forwarding on my router following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44RJDmsNVi4).

I am trying to understand how to ssh access from one machine to another within the local network, and how generally ssh access from outside the network to one of these machines.

All tutorials I read are confusing me.

Can someone instruct me the very precise steps?

Comment: This question is not for SO. Try PuTTY for Windows - enter the WAN IP and port 22.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu not on Windows

Comment: `ssh user@remote-ip-or-domain`. And "outside local network" can be Windows PC with PuTTY client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your tp-link create the following rule:
Source port: 22, ip address: ip of one of the local-LAN host, protocol: TCP, status: enabled.

Moreover, you need to find you **WAN IP** of the tp-link router.
The easiest way is to open a browser on your local-LAN host and google for "what is my ip".

Now, on your external host, run ssh **WAN IP**. You should be able to connect.

If not, make sure ssh server is running on your local-LAN host and firewall allows you in.

Note: if you want to get access to another host in your local-LAN, from the video you attached it seems you need to make additional trick.
On your second local-LAN host you need to change the ssh server port to be something else (e.g. 23) and follow tp-link configuration with source port: 23 and ip address: second local-LAN host ip. Now when you connect from the external host, you need to specify port 23.